# jquery - how do I disable input on multiple select values in an html form?

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a form where some values in a select dropdown need to enable an additional input and some don't. I have two values that need to enable the input and two that need to disable it.

Is there any way to put this in one jquery script as opposed to writing it out again for each value?

I'm new to Jquery so I was wondering if there was a syntax I could use to evaluate two values for the same action.

What I have so far is this...

Jquery:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
     $("#input").attr("disabled", $("#value1").val() == "disable input");
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
      <select class="form-control" name="ship_method" id="ship_method"> 
        <option value=""> ... </option>
        <option value="value1">disable input 1</option>
        <option value="value2">don't disable input 1</option>
        <option value="value3">disable input 2</option>
        <option value="value4">don't disable input 2</option>
      </select>
```

Do I just need to write an additional line that targets "value3," or is there a more streamlined way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the cleanest would be to have an array of values that cause it to be disabled, then see if the value of your `select` is one of those values.

```
$('#input').attr('disabled', 
    ['value1', 'value3'].includes($('#ship_method').val()));
```